# How to show countability of $\omega^\omega$ or $\epsilon_0$ in ZF?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, ordinals

I know that with choice, the countable union of countable sets is countable, making $\omega^\omega$ and $\epsilon_0$ both countable. Can we show this without choice? E.g. in the case that $\omega_1$ is a countable union of countable sets.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Is $2^\omega$ not uncountable?

Comment: I'm sure by $\omega^\omega$, the OP is referring to $\text{sup}\{\omega^n:n<\omega\}$, rather than the set of all functions from $\omega$ into $\omega$.

Comment: @Mark: Ordinal and cardinal exponentiation is very different.

Comment: I feel that this was asked before. But I spent a good 10 minutes trying to find the duplicate without luck. So I wrote an answer instead.

Comment: Ah. [Not quite a duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140392/what-is-the-smallest-possible-value-of-omega-1-in-mathrmzf) but perhaps still relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\omega^\omega$ this is easy. You can note that this is just the order type of $\Bbb N[x]$, the polynomials with natural numbers coefficients, ordered lexicographically by length.

In general, if $\langle A_n\mid n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a sequence of countable sets such that there is a uniformly definable bijection between $A_n$ to $\Bbb N$, then without the axiom of choice we can show that $\bigcup A_n$ is countable.

In the case of $\varepsilon_0$ we can show, without much difficulty that if $\alpha$ is a countable ordinal, then $\omega^\alpha$ is a countable ordinal as well (note that this is ordinal exponentiation). This means that by recursion we can uniformly define bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $\omega,\omega^\omega,\omega^{\omega^\omega},\ldots$ and therefore $\varepsilon_0=\sup\{\omega,\omega^\omega,\ldots\}$ is countable as well.

In general, if $\omega_1$ is a countable union of countable sets, it means that it is a limit cardinal in $L$ (or any other inner model satisfying choice), so it has to be at least $\aleph_\omega$. If you check, you will see that $\varepsilon_0$, and many other "large countable ordinals" have absolute definitions, so they cannot change from $L$ to $V$. So if they are countable in $L$, they will be countable in $V$ as well.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by uniformly defined?

Comment: That there is a formula in the language of set theory, complicated as it may be and with or without parameters, which defines a sequence of bijections between $A_n$ and subsets of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: And so the bijection for $\epsilon_0$ is defined to be the limit of the sequence?

Comment: Well, not necessarily as "the limit", but from the sequence of bijections, or even just injections, we can easily show that there is an injection from the union of the sets (in this case $\varepsilon_0$) into $\Bbb{N\times N}$ which is countable. Therefore it is a countable ordinal.