# (Ordinal number)How to prove that epsilon-naught is countable without using Axiom of Choice?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, ordinals

How to prove that epsilon-naught is countable without using Axiom of Choice?

or, Can we explicitly show that there is isomorpism between epsilon naught and subset of rational number?

Comment: Also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140392/what-is-the-smallest-possible-value-of-omega-1-in-mathrmzf